# Запуск bat файла из python

Tags: python, функции, bat

У меня есть метод, который делает проверку на админку. Но когда я запускаю программу, то выдает ошибку:

```
'Class' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Код:

```py
def run_as_admin(self, cmd):
    try:
        # Если мы не являемся администратором, то запускаем с правами администратора
        if not ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin():
            # Собираем команду, чтобы запустить с правами администратора
            cmd = 'powershell.exe Start-Process "' + cmd + '" -Verb runAs'
            subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
            return True
        # Если мы уже являемся администратором, то просто запускаем файл
        else:
            subprocess.call(cmd)
            return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return False

def buttonDSDel(self):
    self.run_as_admin('Class/DelSoft/DiscordDel.bat')
```

bat file

```
@echo off
taskkill /f /im Discord.exe
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 > nul
cd %appdata%
rmdir /s /q Discord
rmdir /s /q discordptb
rmdir /s /q discordcanary
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

операционная система не может найти файл или команду с названием "Class"

Попробуйте изменить вызов subprocess.call

```
subprocess.call(["powershell.exe", "Start-Process", cmd, "-Verb", "runAs"], shell=True)
```